# Using d3-tip and CSS hover effect with d3 stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart for a simple dataset (Below you can find codes and the data).

For the bar my mouse hovers on, I try to use CSS hover effect to change the color of the bar (A rect svg element with a class of .bar), and use d3-tip to show a tooltip displaying the region name that bar belongs.

Problems I am having are:
1 - The CSS hover effect is not working at all. (Please find the style sheet below)
2 - the tooltip is showing, but only if I move my mouse cursor from under the bar to enter it. If I move my mouse cursor from left/right/top of the bar, the "mouseover" seems like not being detected. When it is not detected, however if you click on the bar, it will be detected and tooltip will show.
3 - The tooltip is supposed to show the data for "d.State" (which is the region's abbreviation text), but it gives me undefined. "d.State" is working fine with the bar chart itself though - the axis ticks are created using these data.

The stacked bar is made based on this one: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

The tooltip and hover effect is based on this one: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

The index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="viz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The viz.js:

```
// begin of the js file
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 320 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 320 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#7b6888", "#a05d56", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

//define tooltip
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Region:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.State + "</span>";
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//call tooltip
svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
          .attr("font-size", 7);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -40)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of Organizations");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",1)"; });

  state.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
      .on("mouseover", tip.show)
      .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
// end of the js file
```

The style.css:

```
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: steelblue;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

The data.csv:

```
State,Non Profit,For Profit,Developer Group,Other
EP,28,142,15,16
EC,81,292,39,22
LC,73,91,23,9
MN,3,5,2,1
NA,102,561,26,19
SA,11,49,9,4
SS,28,10,10,3
```

If there is any part not clear please let me know. I am new to d3 and stackoverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The CSS hover effect is not working at all.(not was missing I guess ?)

   The problem was it was already filled using d3. To override it just add !important to on hover fill

   fill: steelblue !important;
2. The tooltip is showing, but only if I move my mouse cursor from under the bar to enter it. If I move my mouse cursor from left/right/top of the bar.(I didn't face any issue with your code ?)

   I am not sure what exactly is the problem but, my guess is that, onmouseover will work only when you hover on it. So if the mouse pointer is already on the graph before it was generated, it won't show the tooltip.
3. The tooltip is supposed to show the data for "d.State".

   The problem here is the State data is not attached to the element i.e, d.ages doesn't contain state value. Just attach the state value while binding data.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 320 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 320 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#7b6888", "#a05d56", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

//define tooltip
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Region:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.State + "</span>";
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//call tooltip
svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
          .attr("font-size", 7);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -40)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of Organizations");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",1)"; });

  state.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(function(d) {
    for(var l = 0 ; l < d.ages.length ; l++) {
   d.ages[l].State = d.State;
  }
    return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
      .on("mouseover", tip.show)
      .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: steelblue !important;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="viz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think it solves all my problems :)